# Color selector for vector image doesn't work

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics

I have a vector image (svg converted to xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:better="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="NewApi"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    better:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    better:viewportHeight="24"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M10.09 15.59l1.41 1.41 5 -5 -5 -5 -1.41 1.41 2.58 2.59 -9.67 0 0 2 9.67 0 -2.58 2.59zM19 3L5 3C3.89 3 3 3.9 3 5l0 4 2 0 0 -4 14 0 0 14 -14 0 0 -4 -2 0 0 4c0 1.1 0.89 2 2 2l14 0c1.1 0 2 -0.9 2 -2L21 5C21 3.9 20.1 3 19 3Z"
        better:pathData="M10.09 15.59l1.41 1.41 5 -5 -5 -5 -1.41 1.41 2.58 2.59 -9.67 0 0 2 9.67 0 -2.58 2.59zM19 3L5 3C3.89 3 3 3.9 3 5l0 4 2 0 0 -4 14 0 0 14 -14 0 0 -4 -2 0 0 4c0 1.1 0.89 2 2 2l14 0c1.1 0 2 -0.9 2 -2L21 5C21 3.9 20.1 3 19 3Z"
        android:fillColor="@color/menu_color_selector"
        better:fillColor="@color/menu_color_selector" />
</vector>
```

But the color selector doesn't work. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: what is `better:viewportHeight="24"` ? `better:viewportHeight`, `better:pathData` etc, why do you duplicate everything?

Comment: Backport library for working with vector images on old android versions.
https://github.com/a-student/BetterVectorDrawable

Comment: i removed any `android:*` duplicates (if you are using BatterVectorDrawable, so why to use "worse") and it just works

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will check it.

Comment: update: ooops, sorry color selector does not work, i was mistaken

Comment: In any case thanks for your participation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) with different `VectorDrawable` for each required state.